# iOS: KVC, when I exit of my app, there comes a issue with KVC

Tags: ios, kvc

I use `kvc` in my code.

```
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"type" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew |NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"location" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew |NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
```

And I also take the function here:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context {

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"location"] || [keyPath isEqualToString:@"type"]) {

        // refresh data
        if (self.currentTableView == _sellTableView) {

            [self addSellDataSourceWithFlag:1];
        }else {
            [self addBuyDataSourceWithFlag:1];
        }
    }
}
```

In dealloc, I remove them.

```
- (void)dealloc {

    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"location"];
    [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"type"];
}
```

But, when I logout my app:

```
// exit
- (IBAction)exitButtonPress:(UIButton *)sender {


    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = YES;


    self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;


    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"0" forKey:@"user_isLogin"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


    [self.tabBarController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
    }];

}
```

There become an issue, with the `All Exceptions`, it appears the row:

```
[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"location"];
```

The issue info is below:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception
```

And when I `bt`:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x387c7, 0x000000010a6dbf06 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x000000010a6dbf06 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 10
    frame #1: 0x000000010a6a34ec libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill + 90
    frame #2: 0x000000010a43dcec libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 129
    frame #3: 0x000000010a23c051 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 257
    frame #4: 0x000000010a25f292 libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 44
    frame #5: 0x000000010a25eef9 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 99
    frame #6: 0x0000000107b3cf5e libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 40
    frame #7: 0x000000010831e1b4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 676
    frame #8: 0x000000010a83ead2 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 161
    frame #9: 0x0000000108cc3f09 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 171
  * frame #10: 0x00000001047d5b8f E农通`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5b562638) + 111 at main.m:14
    frame #11: 0x000000010a39792d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
    frame #12: 0x000000010a39792d libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

How to solve this issue with `kvc`?

Comment: Did you mean KVO(Key-Value Observing) instead of KVC?

Comment: What is the class doing this observing?  Also that stacktrace doesn't match the `removeObserver:` statement...

Comment: And it is very bad idea to use KVO to monitor own changes. Why can't you just override `type` and `location` methods, call super implementation and refresh data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LeoMaer,

You might be trying to remove the observer even before you have added it. So the solution is to make sure that you have added it before removing the observer.

Try adding your observer either in init or viewDidLoad of your class and then remove it in dealloc.

On the other hand if you have some specific requirement and you have to add it based on condition or something like that use this to avoid crash.

This will remove observer if added else exception will be catched and wont crash

```
@try{
   [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"location"];
}@catch(id anException){
   //catch the exception
}
```

Comment: Hiding the problems under the carpet?

Comment: @trojanfoe : Not really, I have suggested him to ensure he has added the observer before removing it but see sometimes you may add observer based on condition and condition might not be true always so you might end up not adding observer and unfortunately in iOS you cant check if observer has been added or not so blindly removing causes crash so rather then having a crash catching it is better I feel :) and moreover all the answers for checking observer added or not suggests the same thing :) I dont personally like observer and notification design pattern though but it might help someone.

Comment: @Sandeep Bhandari: Does this work?
for (NSString *keyPath in [self observableKeypaths]) {
  [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:keyPath];
 }

Comment: @LeoMaer : You accepted the answer so I thought you will be able to answer it better :) And if you your question is how does this work ?? When you put any statement which might cause exception and on executing that statement if execption occurs and the statement throws the exception because the statement is placed inside the try block execption will be capturred for error handling and code in catch block will be executed :) In this case you dont have to do anything so I have written no comment :) OS will assume that because you have captured it you musta have handled it and so will not

Comment: continue it further down the hirarchy :) Thats what happens when an execption occurs and you dont catch it using try catch block :) Execption will move up the hirarchy searching for someone who can handle it when no body handles it and reaches the end OS stops execution saying dude that was an exception and you din handle it what do you expect me to handle it I'll stop the execution itself :) Thats all :)

Comment: @leomaer : To be frank never tried observableKeypaths before so no idea of consiquences :) I have used the one I posted above and never had any issue with it :) So you will have to figure out on your own buddy if you want to use observableKeypaths :) one doubt if another class say xyz adds observer for keypath called abc then when you say observableKeypaths will it not return abc ?? If it does your app will crash again isn't it Desclaimer : I have never used observableKeypaths before :)

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue, I have got a solution.

Take a @property `NSMutableArray *observe_arr;`and if excutive the `[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"observeName" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew |NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];`
add the `observeName` to the `observe_arr`.

In the dealloc:

```
- (void)dealloc {

    while (self.observe_arr.firstObject) {

        [self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:self.observe_arr.firstObject];
    }
}
```

By the way, thanks a lot of Sandeep Bhandari's help.

Comment: Sounds intersting :) I'll give a try next time :) Hence up-vote :) But dont you think in order for this loop to finish executing you should remove the observeName from self.observe_arr after removing the observer for that key ???? Anyway I believe this code on using as it is will crash again :) Modify the code before somebody points out and down vote :)